# What's wrong with the wiring of my multiplexer?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, multiplexer, teensy

[image: mux]

My circuit is wired as shown above -but with the EN pin I've tried connecting to ground and to power. I don't think its a code problem because when I wire inputs in directly everything reads normal.
I'm using a CD74HC4067 analog multiplexer. The T4 refers to my Teensy4.0 microcontroller, its hooked up to the breadboard ground and I have tried using both the 3.3V and 5V power pins hooked up to the red line on the breadboard and had identical results between either. The signal pins of the mux are routed to my digital pins on my T4 and the signal is hooked up to an analog pin on the board. The larger components in my diagram are B100k/b20k potentiometers and the smaller ones are tactile buttons.

With this wiring hookup, adjusting the first potentiometer from the left appears to change the signal reading for most of the other input channels. Pressing the first button from the left also was effecting the readings on channels 8-11, and one of the buttons was effecting the readings of a channel nowhere near it.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: It would help to say what each component is. Like what is the multiplexer type?

Comment: Please use CircuitLab to do a basic schematic.

Comment: @Justme sorry forgot to add the mux. its a CD74HC4067 analog multiplexer

Comment: Pin 15 is INHIBIT and should be tied low (ground). Test your system in slow motion: leave the 4 select bits in one position and confirm with a volt meter that the selected input shows up on the Common pin and no other inputs affect it. Repeat for all settings. If things look good with these static settings then the problem could be in the software - going through the channels too fast perhaps.